# How to log all the methods which are accessed/executed in processing a request without using any external mechanisams like log, etc

Tags: java

How to log all the methods which are accessed/executed in processing a request without using any external mechanisms like log4j, etc.

Comment: What exactly do you want to avoid? Do you mean no *intrusive* mechanisms like logging--methods that require code modification?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple, you cannot.  You need to do SOMETHING to "observe" your running application.

What you can do is hook up a profiler, which requires you to be running some agent on the JDK hosting your application.  The profiler can be used to record how many times each method was called and how long it spent there and the like.  VisualVM is a "free option" here.  If you pay, YourKit and the like can give you deeper insights.

You could grab a CodaHale or Prometheus or some metrics framework and instrument the methods you are interested in in terms of counters and timers and the like.  The benefit is you code this stuff up and it is always available, but it does require coding.